# a word that would mean "a marriage where either of the spouse is of a higher rank or caste"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I was writing an essay when I used the word morganatic and I realized I don't quite know the word for a marriage between people of unequal ranks that society holds as unfair or against the norms. it can be related to a marriage or relation and mean similar to what I described.

Comment: Check out **Morganatic** at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morganatic_marriage lots of detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **hypergamy** [(colloquially referred to as "marrying up") is the act or practice of marrying someone of higher caste or status than oneself.[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergamy)

Answer (score 3):

Also consider the term  *mesalliance*,   “a marriage with a person of inferior social position” ([1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/m%C3%A9salliance),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesalliance),[3](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=mesalliance)).

From [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=mesalliance):

> mesalliance (n.)
>   “marriage with a person of lower social position,” 1782, from French *mésalliance*, from pejorative prefix *mes-* (from Latin *mis-*; see [*mis-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mis-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *alliance* (see [*alliance*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=alliance&allowed_in_frame=0)).

Answer (score 2):

*inter-class* marrige should be a possibile definition.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, in the UK, this would have been described as an **unequal marriage.** This term will sound old-fashioned to an American English speaker, and probably in the UK too; then again, the concept is fairly outdated as well.

In the United States, the concern is more likely to be related to money than to social class. The derogatory term used for a woman who marries a richer man is **gold-digger;** the man she marries would be a **sugar daddy** or **meal ticket.** A man might be be described as a **gigolo,** by analogy to an actual gigolo or paid companion.